# Why can't Thunderbolt be replaced with a PCI Express cable?

Tags: thunderbolt

It wouldn't be able to directly run displays, but why couldn't Apple have just used the PCI Express 3.0 pins for high speed data transfers (modifying it somewhat to account for the additional latency, etc.)?

Is it because the signal wouldn't travel as far?

Comment: Compare https://www.google.fr/search?q=pci+express+3.0+cable&tbm=isch with https://www.google.fr/search?q=thunderbolt+cable&tbm=isch. It doesn't seem to fit the same usage, does it?

Comment: The better alternative would have been 50GBit ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is effectively ExpressCard. That uses one lane of PCIe Gen 1 or 2 and you can get cables to extend it out to backplanes.

Thunderbolt 1&2 have two high speed lanes which can transfer DP or PCIe Gen 1 or 2. So you have more expandability.

Thunderbolt 3 (which is now Intel rather than Apple) on the other hand has 4 high speed lanes which can transfer PCIe Gen 3 aggregated with a display port interface and USB 3.1. This is comparatively far more useful then ExpressCard because it can do far more. You will be able to get TB3->PCIe enclosures so you can still bring out PCIe over a thunderbolt cable, but at the same time as doing that you can also deliver video data, USB, and various other protocols through just one port. The connector is also tiny which helps for smaller devices.

For desktops it is possible to get add-in cards which route PCIe lanes out to cables via optical fibres (and copper cables) which can then be used with large backplanes and external devices (e.g. an array of compute cards).

Comment: Don't forget that TB3 can source up to 100W of power.